# Legend data in jfreechart goes outside boundary box

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a problem with jfreechart, the legend data goes outside the boundary box, this is only seen in Windows, not seen in Linux. Does anyone face this issue? I am using jfreechart version 1.0.12
Please refer the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgGpQ.png)

Comment: Please switch to the current version and edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117791).